# Using existing code, implement PAGINATION using MYSQLI/PHP

Tags: php, html, list, mysqli, pagination

i have existing code, I read a lot of example of using Pagination, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my case.

**VIEW.php**

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
echo "<div class=\"maincover \" data-role=\"scrollbox\" data-scroll=\"vertical\">";

echo "<div class=\"panel panel-default\">";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<div class=\"panel-heading\">";
echo '<div><a class="panel-title btn-block" href="details.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><h3>'.$row['id'].' | '.$row['vidTitle'].'</h3></a></div>';
echo "</div>";

echo "<div class=\"panel-body\">";
echo "<div class=\"imgCover\"><img class=\"imageCover\"src=\"" . $row['url'] . "\"></div>";
echo "<div class=\"vidSD\">" . $row['vidSD'] . "</div>";
echo "<div class=\"vidDetails\"> 

<hr class=\"style-two\">
<table>
<tr><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\"><strong>" . $lang['vtYear'] . "</strong></td><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\">" . $row['vidYear'] ."</td></tr>
<tr><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\"><strong>" . $lang['vtCity'] . "</strong></td><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\">". $row['vidCity'] ."</td></tr>
<tr><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\"><strong>" . $lang['vtGenre'] . "</strong></td><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\">". $row['vidZanr'] ." , ". $row['vidZanr2'] ." , ". $row['vidZanr3'] . "</td></tr>
<tr><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\"><strong>" . $lang['vtQuality'] . "</strong></td><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\">". $row['vidQuality'] ."</td></tr>
<tr><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\"><strong>" . $lang['vtTranslatedBy'] . "</strong></td><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\">". $row['vidTranslated'] ."</td></tr>
<tr><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\"><strong>" . $lang['vtVideoTime'] . "</strong></td><td class=\"vidDetailsTD\">". $row['vidTime'] .  "</td></tr>
</table> 
</div></div>";

echo " <div class=\"panel-footer\">";
echo '<h6><strong>' . $lang['vsdAuthor'] . '</strong><a href="../userPages/user.php?u='.$row['addName'].'">'.$row['addName'].'</a></h6>';
echo '<div><h6><strong>' . $lang['vsdPublished'] . '</strong>' . $row['published'] . '</h6></div>'; 
echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div></div>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This code displaying a list of videos, and I'm not sure how to ADD pagination at the bottom of this list, using **MY** code.

This is what I found:
**[SampleOne](http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1349) [SampleTwo](https://github.com/BenGriffiths/pdo-mysqli-pagination) [SampleThree](http://www.thaicreate.com/php/php-mysql-mysqli-search-paging.html)**

And because I have sorting list, it's even more problematically, HAVE NO IDEA how to do it ((

**sortOrder.php**

```
<?php


$query ="SELECT newsvid.id, newsvid.addName, newsvid.vidTitle, newsvid.vidType, newsvid.size, newsvid.url, newsvid.vidSD, newsvid.published, videoinformation.vidLD, videoinformation.vidYear, videoinformation.vidCity, videoinformation.vidZanr, videoinformation.vidZanr2, videoinformation.vidZanr3, videoinformation.vidQuality, videoinformation.vidTranslated, videoinformation.vidTime  FROM newsvid, videoinformation WHERE newsvid.id = videoinformation.id";



// Video type
$vType = isset($_GET['vType']) ? $_GET['vType'] : 'ALL';
$goodTypeParam = array("AnyType", "Film", "Serials", "Cartoon", "Anime");

if (in_array($vType, $goodTypeParam)) {
    if($vType == 'AnyType'){}
    else{$query .= " AND newsvid.vidType ='".$_GET['vType']."'";}
}




//Video Genre one
$vGenre = isset($_GET['vGenre']) ? $_GET['vGenre'] : 'ALL';
$goodGenreParam = array("AnyGenre1", "Action", "Adventure", "Comedy", "Crime", "Faction", "Fantasy", "Historical", "Horror", "Mystery", "Paranoid", "Philosophical", "Political", "Realistic", "Romance", "Saga", "Satire", "Science-Fiction", "Slice-Of-Life", "Speculative", "Anime");

if (in_array($vGenre, $goodGenreParam)) {
    if($vGenre == 'AnyGenre1'){}
    else{$query .= " AND ( videoinformation.vidZanr ='".$_GET['vGenre']."' OR videoinformation.vidZanr2 ='".$_GET['vGenre']."' OR videoinformation.vidZanr3 ='".$_GET['vGenre']."')";}
}

//Video Genre two
$vGenre2 = isset($_GET['vGenre2']) ? $_GET['vGenre2'] : 'ALL';
$goodGenre2Param = array("AnyGenre2", "Action2", "Adventure2", "Comedy2", "Crime2", "Faction2", "Fantasy2", "Historical2", "Horror2", "Mystery2", "Paranoid2", "Philosophical2", "Political2", "Realistic2", "Romance2", "Saga2", "Satire2", "Science-Fiction2", "Slice-Of-Life2", "Speculative2", "Anime2");

if (in_array(vGenre2, $goodGenre2Param)) {
    if(vGenre2 == 'AnyGenre2'){}
    else{$query .= " AND ( videoinformation.vidZanr ='".$_GET['vGenre2']."' OR videoinformation.vidZanr2 ='".$_GET['vGenre2']."' OR videoinformation.vidZanr3 ='".$_GET['vGenre2']."')";}
}

//Video Genre three
$vGenre3 = isset($_GET['vGenre3']) ? $_GET['vGenre3'] : 'ALL';
$goodGenre3Param = array("AnyGenre3", "Action", "Adventure", "Comedy", "Crime", "Faction", "Fantasy", "Historical", "Horror", "Mystery", "Paranoid", "Philosophical", "Political", "Realistic", "Romance", "Saga", "Satire", "Science-Fiction", "Slice-Of-Life", "Speculative", "Anime");

if (in_array($vGenre, $goodGenre3Param)) {
    if($vGenre3 == 'AnyGenre3'){}
    else{$query .= " AND ( videoinformation.vidZanr ='".$_GET['vGenre3']."' OR videoinformation.vidZanr2 ='".$_GET['vGenre3']."' OR videoinformation.vidZanr3 ='".$_GET['vGenre3']."')";}
}





// Video Years
$vYear = isset($_GET['vYear']) ? $_GET['vYear'] : 'ALL';
$goodYearParam = array("AnyYear", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2010", "2009", "2008", "2007", "2006", "2005", "2004", "2003", "2002", "2001", "2000", "1999", "1998", "1997");

if (in_array($vType, $goodYearParam)) {
    if($vYear == 'AnyYear'){}
    else{$query .= " AND newsvid.vidYear ='".$_GET['vYear']."'";}
}


// Video City
$vCity = isset($_GET['vCity']) ? $_GET['vCity'] : 'ALL';
$goodCityParam = array("AnyCity", "Russian", "England");

if (in_array($vCity, $goodCityParam)) {
    if($vCity == 'AnyCity'){}
    else{$query .= " AND newsvid.vidCity ='".$_GET['vCity']."'";}
}



//NEW of OLD
$order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : 'ALL';
$goodParam = array("NEW", "OLD");

if (in_array($order, $goodParam)) {

    if($order == 'NEW'){
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.id ASC"; 
    }else if($order == 'OLD'){
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.id DESC"; 
    }else{
     $query .= " AND videoinformation.vidYear = 2014"; 
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: Cool, i told in the question, I know theoretically, I know that I need display limitation and so on... but physically (with my code) I can't understand how to implement it with my code.

Comment: view my answer, it has detailed steps on what you need to do in order to add a pagination to your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why is your HTML inside your PHP? if your going the old-fashioned way without using any modern template engine then you should at least not put the HTML inside of your PHP code.

about your question, you should just create a PHP script that will handle an offset/limit parameters. and will adjust the SQL Query.

There's a few steps you need to do in order to accomplish what you want to do.

1. use GET parameter in order to know on which page you are on `$page=$_GET['page']`
2. use $offset and $limit parameters in order to paginate.
3. `$offset = ($page-1) * 10; $limit = 10; // constant limit per page`
4. return the COUNT of the total amount of rows from your query with
   out any LIMIT & OFFSET.
5. use Limit & Offset in the same query and return the rows MySQL lets assume our $offset is 0 and $limit is 10. `LIMIT 0,10` / `$query .= "LIMIT $offset, $limit";`
6. you can now display all of the rows you've got back from the previous query. (10 rows in our example for the first page).
7. lets assume the 1 step return that you have total of 100 rows. now you need to display the pagination in your page your current offset is 0 and the limit per page is 10 (from our`LIMIT 0,10` example).
   and you need to check the total amount of pages `$total_pages = ceil($totalRows / $rows_per_page)` = (100/10 = 10).
8. loop on the total_pages and create links

:

```
for ($page = 1; $page < $total_pages; ++$page) {
     echo "<a href=\"list.php?page={$page}\">{$page}</a>";
}
```

Comment: @Denis, no body is going to code for you. take this as a lesson. follow the steps, it has detailed information on exactly what you need to do. if you are still stuck. edit your answer with the code you've reached so far and we will go from there.